# Creating colored bars for poll results

Tags: html, css

In my web app I'd like to display poll results with colored bars with length proportional to the percentage of votes. How can I achieve this with HTML/CSS?

Answer (score 3):

This site contains some nice examples:

http://apples-to-oranges.com/blog/post/css-for-bar-graphs/?id=55

And here is a collection of 16 different types of bar graphs:

http://speckyboy.com/2009/02/04/16-usable-css-graph-and-bar-chart-tutorials-and-techniques/

Answer (score 3):

Here is some example code:

```
        <style>
        .GraphWrapper {
            width:300px;
            border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
        }

        .BlueBar {
            height:30px;
            margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
            background-color:#FFCCCC;
        }

        .RedBar {
            height:30px;
            margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
            background-color:#CCCCFF;
        }
    </style>

    <div class='GraphWrapper'>
        <div class='BlueBar' style='width:50%;'></div>
        <div class='RedBar' style='width:75%;'></div>
    </div>
```

You can then edit the **width style** of your graph bars to achieve the graph percentage.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple to pull off. You want each bar to be represented by a single . Set the div to the width that you want (proportional to the results). For example if you want 200px to be "100%" of the vote, then if an option has 23% of the vote you want .23 * 200 to be the pixel width of the div.

Then set the background color and border to style the bar as you desire. You can also get fancy and use images (background-image css property) to get nicer looking bars.

I hope that points you in the right direction.

Comment: If you want 23% width, why not simply set width to 23%? :p

Comment: Sometimes one misses the obvious, especially before their morning coffee :p 

Although in fairness, using percentages could make for trickier CSS. I wanted to make sure it was clear how to calculate the relative width.

Comment: because you want it dynamic with back end data basedon the # of votes

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but new technology has provided a new solution.  Also, none of the answers is accepted...

In HTML5, you can use a [canvas element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) to actually draw your graph.  Using the canvas element can be very complex, so I won't go into full detail here about how to use this for your specific scenario.

However, here's a simple example (copied from [diveintohtml5.info](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)):

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="graph" width="300" height="225"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("graph");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillRect(50, 24, 150, 100);
```