# How to sum a field in a List(Of xx)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have:

```
 Dim aList As List(Of myObj.Answers) = myObj.GetResults(someID)
```

This returns:

```
aList.AnswerID | aList.AnswerCount
      1                 3
      2                 5
      3                 9
```

How can I get the sum of aList.AnswerCount field in my List(Of myObj) ?

Comment: I would have written if I tried anything. It is the first time I am dealing with this so did not try anything!.. Is this satisfactory for you Mr. Oded? or will you come up with another link?

Comment: Here you go: [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html). In a particulary appropriate post by Jeff Atwood just yesterday.

Comment: you should work for dmoz Oded!

Comment: @ShaiCohen - Does [this](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/27745.html) fit?

Comment: Emin - I expect those who ask questions to put some effort and research into their questions and post what they have tried and where they are having problems. Is that too much to ask for?

Comment: @Oded As usual you eloquently put into words what I was thinking.

Comment: I try to do what you suggest in most of my questions. In this particular question, both the question and the content is self explanatory. Any more info would bu excess info. Before I ask any question, I also try to be simple. I have seen too many users just copying/pasting source code expecting people to solve their problems for them. I am trying not to be one of them. I did not include more info also because this was the first time I was dealing with it and would like to have as many opinions as possible. Providing examples would force people to try and help in MY way when needed theirs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920635/creating-colored-bars-for-poll-results 
tell me about this question then... I could just go and ask "I need a poll app. Please somebody write the code for it and send to me!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a simple sum, it's quite easy:

```
aList.Sum(Function(i) i.AnswerCount)
```

Comment: I think this is invalid VB syntax. At least my converter (http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) says it should be written differently in VB.NET

Comment: this is the vb version which worked.. 
aList.Sum(Function(i) i.AnswerCount)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim total  = aList.Sum(function(x) x.AnswerCount)
```

Not sure about the VB syntax but it should be something along those lines.

Comment: thank you Icarus for the answer, I tried your suggestion as well, which worked!

Answer (score 0):

`dim result = aList.Select(function(a) a.AnswerCount).Sum()`

Something like that?